# InvalidClientTokenId when calling get-caller-identity on an AWS EC2 instance with instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sts

We're having an issue where we're on a CentOS EC2 instance that is using a role through an attached instance profile. When we're on the console after SSHing in, we run the python `awscli` command line tool to get our identity:

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
```

we're getting

> An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid

other commands, such as `aws ec2 describe-instances` work and are allowed by the instance profile.

From reading the AWS documentation, no permissions should be required to get-caller-identity and there's no explicit `deny` set on the role associated with instance.

We checked and there's no `.aws/credentials` file and no `env` variables set, so access should be entirely managed through the metadata service on the EC2 instance.

Is there something missing in our setup or invocation of the `awscli` that might cause the permission to fail?

Answer (score 2):

Just documenting the fix for anyone that runs into this issue.

All calls to the `awscli` should probably include a `--region <region>` parameter.

E.g.

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity --region us-east-2
```

We were prompted for the region on our `aws ec2 describe-instances` call but on the `aws sts get-caller-identity` call, it just failed.

Additionally, we found that the `AWS_REGION` environment variable didn't seem to affect calls: we still needed to include the `--region <region>` parameter.

Comment: The environmental variable to set is `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html